# Error login python CSRF

Tags: python, django, forms

When I submit the login form, I get the following error :

```
403 Forbidden Reason given for failure:CSRF token missing or incorrect.
```

Here is my code

**urls.py**

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from app.models import *
from app.views import *

admin.autodiscover()
# Uncomment the next lines to enable the admin:

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    url('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', namespace='auth')),
    url(r'^social/',include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
    #url(r'^s$', 'app.views.CategoriaProductoss', name='servicios'),
    #url(r'^s/(?P<id>\d+)$', 'app.views.servicioscategoria', name='servicioscategoria'),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve', {'document_root':settings.MEDIA_ROOT,}),
    url(r'^$', 'app.views.index', name='Vulpini.co'),
    url(r'^login$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='Vulpini.co'),
    url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', name='logout'),
    url(r'start$', 'app.views.start', name="start"),
    url(r'ajax-upload$', 'app.views.import_uploader', name="my_ajax_upload"),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
     url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Here is the template where I have my form:

**Layout.html**

```
<form action="/login" class="form-horizontal" formmethod="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <h4>Iniciar Sesion.</h4>
   <hr />
   <div class="login-social">                     
      <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?next={{ request.path }}" target="iframe">Iniciar sesion con Facebook</a>           
      <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'twitter' %}?next={{ request.path }}" target="iframe">Iniciar sesion con Twitter</a>
   </div>
   <hr />
   <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Usuario</label>
        <div class="controls">
           <input name="username" type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Usuario"/>
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Contraseña</label>
        <div class="controls">
           <input name="password" type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
        </div>
     </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" />Recordar</label>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" formmethod="post" formaction="/login">Ingresar</button>
            <a href="/">Registrar</a>
   </div>
</form>
```

Why do I get a CSRF failure even though I have included `{% csrf_token %}` on my form?

Comment: What does the rendered html template look like? Is the csrf token there? What does `request.POST` look like when you submit the form? Do you get the same error if you use `method='post'` on your form, and a regular `<input type="submit" />` instead of the button?

Comment: @Alasdair looks it's my views, `def index(request):
    notifi = Notificaciones.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('app/index.html',{ 'notifi' : notifi })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The csrf token tag needs access to the `request` object. In your case, the easiest way to do this is to use the `render` shortcut instead of `render_to_response`.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    notifi = Notificaciones.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'app/index.html', {'notifi': notifi})
```

Comment: now when i submit form sign, appears this `
Exception Type:
TemplateDoesNotExist 
Exception Value:
registration/login.html`.

Comment: That's a separate issue. If the built in login view fails, it renders the login template, showing the errors. Therefore [you need to create a template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.login)   `registration/login.html`.

Comment: sorry i don't catch it, i don't have a fold call registration, have i create a fold call so and in **URL** call registration/login.html

Comment: In your templates folder create a folder `registration`, and in that folder create a template `login.html`. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.login) for more info.